# I want value instead of id in django after left join

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, mysql-python

Hi i have three tables in models.py and i perform Left Join. When i render data in template after join i get job_no as id instead of value. Can u help me to get the original value instead of id.

```
class Job(models.Model):
job_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class RecievableInvoice(models.Model):
invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
invoice_amount = models.IntegerField()
job_no = models.ForeignKey(Job,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class PayableInvoice(models.Model):
invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
invoice_amount = models.IntegerField()
job_no = models.ForeignKey(Job,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is my query

```
cursor.execute(''' Select RecievableInvoice.job_no,RecievableInvoice.invoice_no,RecievableInvoice.invoice_amount,
     PayableInvoice.invoice_no,PayableInvoice.invoice_amount, FROM RecievableInvoice LEFT JOIN PayableInvoice
     ON RecievableInvoice.job_no = PayableInvoice.job_no''')
```

Screenshot Attached

[image: Instead of ID i want value in Job No Coloumn but now its shows id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
 cursor.execute(''' Select Job.job_no,RecievableInvoice.invoice_no,RecievableInvoice.invoice_amount,
 PayableInvoice.invoice_no,PayableInvoice.invoice_amount, FROM RecievableInvoice LEFT JOIN PayableInvoice
 ON RecievableInvoice.job_no = PayableInvoice.job_no LEFT JOIN Job
 ON RecievableInvoice.job_no = Job.job_no ''')
```

Comment: Thanks i got the expected result as here is just a change instead of job_no i take id at the end of the query